# How to correctly translate Kmeans labels to category labels

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, label

I have been using Sklearn's Kmeans implementation

I have been clustering a dataset which is labeled, and I have been using sklearn's [clustering metrics](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#clustering-metrics) in order to test the clustering performance.

Sklearn's Kmeans clustering output is as you know a list of numbers in the range of `k_clusters`. However my labels are `strings`.

So far I had no problems with them since the metrics from `sklearn.metrics.cluster` work with mixed inputs (`int` & `str` label lists).

However now I want to use some of the [classification metrics](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#classification-metrics) and from what I gather, the inputs `k_true` and `k_pred` need to be of the same set. Either numbers in range of `k`, or then string labels that my dataset is using. If I try it, it returns the following error:

`AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'sum'`

So, how could I translate the `k_means` labels into an other type of labels? Or even the other way around (string labels -> integer labels).

How could I even begin implementing it? Since k_means is pretty non-deterministic, the labels might change from iteration to iteration. Is there a legit way in order to correctly translate Kmeans labels?

EDIT:

*EXAMPLE*

for k = 4

kmeans output: `[0,3,3,2,........0]`

class labels : `['CAT','DOG','DOG','BIRD',.......'CHICKEN']`

Comment: @MohammedKashif I added an example of my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clustering is not classification.

The methods do not predict a label, so you **must not use a classification evaluation measure**. That would be like measuring the quality of an apple in miles per gallon...

If you insist on doing the wrong thing(tm) then use the Hungarian algorithm to find the best mapping. But beware: the number of clusters and the number of classes *will* usually not be the same. If this is the case, using such a mapping will either be unfairly negative (not mapping extra clusters) or unfairly positive (mapping !uktiple clusters to the same label will consider the N points are N clusters "solution" optimal). It's better to only use clustering measures.

Comment: About the number of clusters and classes. I will be using kmeans, so I will be *looking* to match the classes. About the measures I suppose you are right. Different metrics for different things. However I think `F1`, `Precision` and `Recall` could apply in clustering right? Anyway thanks for your input. I appreciate it. Cheers

Comment: There are different precision, recall, and F1 for clustering that do not require a 1:1 mapping.

Comment: Oh I see. Any implementation that you know about?

Answer (score 1):

You can create mapping using a dictionary, say

```
mapping_dict = { 0: 'cat', 1: 'chicken', 2:'bird', 3:'dog'}
```

Then you can simply apply this mapping using say list comprehension,etc.
Suppose your labels are stored in a list `kmeans_predictions`

```
mapped_predictions = [ mapping_dict[x] for x in kmeans_predictions]
```

Then use `mapped_predictions` as your predictions

**Update** : Based on your comments, i believe you have to do it the other way round. I mean convert your labels into `int' mappings.

Also, you cannot use just any classification metric here. Use [Completeness score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.completeness_score.html#sklearn.metrics.completeness_score), [v-measure](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.v_measure_score.html#sklearn.metrics.v_measure_score) and [homogenity](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.homogeneity_score.html) as these are more suited for clustering problems. It would be incorrect to just blindly use any random classification metric here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My problem is not the tecnical how, but how to organize the mapping. Which `int` label will be mapped to which `str` label. I could maybe observe the distribution of each cluster, but that could be hiding some traps in the process.